# Want to add eWallet & payment gateway in php laravel (API)

Tags: php, laravel, sdk, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I want to integrate a ewallet with payment gateway that enables users(customers) to add amount to app wallet and use that wallet money to make payment to various business vendors registered to the same application.
Can anyone suggest any ewallet providers like *skrill.com* that do the job,so that I can use them in my application ?

What I have done till now:

1. Started trying skrill.com
2. *https://www.skrill.com/fileadmin/content/pdf/Skrill_Quick_Checkout_Guide.pdf*
3. Contacted skrill support for getting test accounts
4. Searching for resources.Couldn't find proper documentation that can be used for API.

Comment: How does this have two upvotes? This is clearly off topic

Comment: Hi, Since I am new in building an app with wallet like feature I asked for ideas and suggestions.Also I have seen other similar posts asking for suggestions which had appropriate answers.